# View switching between MaterialDrawer layouts

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I need to create two MaterialDrawer for the same activity and switch between them. But I need that items be updated when the Drawer is being displayed on the screen.

With the properties we have for MaterialDrawer, the changes between one drawer layout to other only can be visible after the drawer is closed and you touch the drawer toggle again.

Is it possible to do a refresh in the layout, do a invalidate or do a notify in the changes during the display of the drawer, when switching between drawers, for the changes to be displayed on the fly?

Thank you,
Alexandre Bianchi

Comment: Why do you need 2 different drawers? Isn't it possible to just switch out the items at runtime?

Comment: Hi Mike. it's possible to switch between the items, but I think that only after closing and openning again the material drawer. I want to switch and see the other material drawing change old material drawer just like we can change a text from a textbox. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The `MaterialDrawer` comes with a easy to use API which will allow you to modify the items, shown in the `Drawer` at runtime, without the requirement of creating a new `Drawer` object.

You can remove the current items in the list at any time via the `removeAllItems` method. https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java#L747

And you can easily add new items in the same style via the `addItems` method: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java#L756

These changes will directly reflect in the UI.

For some more complex usecases you can also look into the source code used for the `AccountSwitcher` which will switch 2 lists in the `Drawer` and animate them: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/AccountHeaderBuilder.java#L1348

Comment: Mike, can you provide me an example of Account Switcher use case ? This link you wrote shows the toggleSelectionList method.

Comment: @AlexandreBianchi yes it does. as you want to have to lists handled at the same time. which is independent of the real `AccountSwitcher` used with the `AccountHeader`. The above information just shows the code I use internally to handle to different lists at the same time. You can still go with the above mentioned removeAllItems, addItems variant. Which will basically do the same, without keeping the states